# My Bootstrap form completely disappears due to use of If-else statement with EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```html
<div class="row" style="margin: auto; max-width: 850;">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">User Registration</h1>
                   <!-- <div class="well well-sm"><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" style="color: red"></span>Required Field</strong></div>-->
   <form role="form" action="/users/addUser" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
    
        <div class="span6">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="InputEmail">Username</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="text" style="width: 180%" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required>
                                                
                                                <!--
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                                                -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                    </div>
         </div>
        <div class="span6">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="InputEmail">Password</label>
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <input type="password" style="width: 180%"  class="form-control"  id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
                                                    <!--
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                                                    -->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                    </div>
         </div>
                                <!--
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="InputMessage">Enter Message</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <textarea name="InputMessage" id="InputMessage" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info float-xs-right">-->
                     
               
                <div class="col-lg-5 push-md-1">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <% if(isRegistered) { %>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <%= msg %>.</strong>
                        </div>
                        <% } else { %>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><strong> <%= msg %> </strong>
                        </div>
                        <% } %>
                    </div>
                </div>
              
           

  
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <hr>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info float-xs-right">
            </form>
            </div>
```

As shown above, if i use "If-else " statement with EJS, my form disappears and if i remove it, my form appears on the browser again.

What i'm trying is to have a registration page where if the user already exists, an alert message to be displayed on the corner side of the browser saying, 'user already exists'. By the way this alert message is coming from my db (Oracle 11g).

Comment: Don't post code as image. That's a **pain** to read and we can't copy/paste.

Comment: @Cid, you are right. Thanks.